# Unable to select cloned div in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I'm trying to build a dynamic menu where the sub menus get swapped out.

```
<nav id="main-menu">
    <div id="categories">
        <a id="snacks" class="categ">Snacks &amp; Sweets</a>
        <a id="pantry" class="categ">Pantry</a>
        <a id="home" class="categ">Home &amp; Supplies</a>
        <a id="etc" class="categ">DIY / Hobby</a>
        <a id="fresh" class="categ">Fresh Food</a>
    </div>
    <div id="subcategories" class="scroll-container">

    </div>
    <div id="options" class="scroll-container">

    </div>
</nav>
```

## Javascript

This part works well - when a category is hovered, the second part of the menu gets its listings added in `<div id="subcategories">`.

```
$("#categories a").hover(function() {
    categ = $(this).attr("id");
    subcateg = "sub-" + categ;

    var newDiv = $("#" + subcateg).clone();

    $("#subcategories").html(newDiv);
});
```

This part should have similar functionality, where hovering certain elements in this menu reveals the third menu.

```
$("a").hover(function() {

   let id = $(this).data("menu");
   let option = $("#" + id);

    if (!$(option).hasClass("active-option")) {
        if (id !== undefined && id !== null) {
            div = $("#opt-" + id).clone();
            $("#options").html(div);
            console.log("id is ", id, "option is ", option, "div is ", div);
        }
    }
});
```

The mishap is that jquery doesn't see any of the cloned material. This is can be surely seen with

```
$("a").hover(function() {
    console.log($(this));
}
```

Link to pen: 
http://codepen.io/WallyNally/pen/dWqGEp

Which produces logs for all of the first menu, but none of the second.

Is there a solution to copy elements into a different element while still making it visible?

Comment: You'll need to make sure that the ids aren't the same (jquery will stop looking for matches after the first one, because an id attribute is meant to be unique for a page) or use a different selector

Comment: This seems like a really over-engineered solution if the content is all hard-coded inside the same page.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Come production it will be more dynamic. But it may also be over-engineered for what it is- do you see a more obvious simpler way?

Comment: I would put all the HTML in place, then just hide/show it as needed. You could potentially even make that work without JS if you amend the HTML/CSS

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.on()` in place of `.hover()` (`.hover()` covers two events - `mouseenter` and `mouseexit`.)

```js
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        // your hover code
    }
}, "a"); // or "a.categ, a.menu-item" maybe
```

https://api.jquery.com/hover/

http://api.jquery.com/on/ (see the section on delegated events)

**edit:** fixed "backwards" curly bracket